# Simple jQuery - Appending to body causes following code to not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do two things:

1. Append a div to the body
2. Make all clicks to links class `editlink` make a popup and not go to their href

Doing just #2 is fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//  $(body).append("<div>Hello world</div>");
  $("a.editlink").click(function(event){
    alert("Javascript-endabled users should see this");
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

But if I uncomment the code for #1 like below,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(body).append("<div>Hello world</div>");
  $("a.editlink").click(function(event){
    alert("Javascript-endabled users should see this");
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

the div appears as expected, but clicking `editlink` links no longer gives me a popup and navigates to the link's href.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean:

```
$("body")
```

rather than:

```
$(body)
```

?

Can I recommend that you use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to get decent error reporting?  You'd have found this very quickly with Firebug.

Comment: thanks for the firebug reference. I actually have it installed but am not sure how to use the error reporting thing

Comment: Enable the `console`. Whenever an uncaught exception happens, a red icon will show in the bottom right corner, and it will count the number of errors. Clicking it will open the console, where you can see what is the exception and where it happened.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the quotes for your **body** tag selector:

```
$('body').append("<div>Hello world</div>");
```